# Winforms - Underline part of text to be displayed in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a line of text to display and what I want to do is underline only the heading portion of the text in the display. How do I accomplish this please?

Message: This is a message for Name of Client.

Where "Message:" is underlined.

Comment: You are using the wrong control for this. If you really feel an overwhelming reason to do that underline then choose the RichTextBox.

Comment: I have never used one of these before. How do I format the text to underline the part of the string I need it to please?

Comment: What is the text you are trying to display?  How do you know which part of the text is the heading?

Comment: It depends what kind of control you are wanting to display the text in.  If the text is being displayed in labels, you need to use multiple labels, one for each font type.  If you want them to dynamically reposition themselves as their content changes, you'd want to put them in a FlowLayoutPanel, or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the text using a rich text box, you could do something like this:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Underline);
richTextBox1.SelectedText = "Message:";
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
richTextBox1.SelectedText = " This is a message for Name of Client.";
```

Or, if the message is dynamic and the header and text are always separated by a colon, you could do something like this:

```
string message = "Message: This is a message for Name of Client";
string[] parts = message.Split(':');
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Underline);
richTextBox1.SelectedText = parts[0] + ":";
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
richTextBox1.SelectedText = parts[1];
```

Or, if you want to show the text dynamically in labels, you could do something like this:

```
string message = "Message: This is a message for Name of Client";
string[] parts = message.Split(':');

Label heading = new Label();
heading.Text = parts[0] + ":";
heading.Font= new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Underline);
heading.AutoSize = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(heading);

Label message = new Label();
message.Text = parts[1];
message.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
message.AutoSize = true;
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(message);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tdc88y7.aspx) instead !

```
    this.myRichTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
    this.myRichTextBox.SelectionLength = this.contactsTextBox.Text.Length-1;
    myRichTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(myRichTextBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
    this.myRichTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that underline using the RichTextBox control

```
  int start = rtbTextBox.Text.IndexOf("Message:", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
  if(start > 0)
  {
       rtbTextBox.SelectionStart = start;         
       rtbTextBox.SelectionLength = "Message:".Length-1;         
       rtbTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(rtbTextBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
       rtbTextBox.SelectionLength = 0; 
  }
```

This example use directly the text you provided in your question. It will be better if you  encapsulate this code in a private method and pass in the heading text.

For example:

```
private void UnderlineHeading(string heading)
{
    int start = rtbTextBox.Text.IndexOf(heading, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    if(start > 0)
    {
         rtbTextBox.SelectionStart = start;         
         rtbTextBox.SelectionLength = heading.Length-1;         
         rtbTextBox.SelectionFont = new Font(rtbTextBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline);
         rtbTextBox.SelectionLength = 0; 
    }
}
```

and call from your form whith: `UnderlineHeading("Message:");`

Comment: WoW, I swear I write it, we finished almost same :)

Comment: I updated my original post with a sample of the string. What I want is to specify that only the beginning text on the particular line be underlined.

Comment: I have updated my answer using the text and position you have supplied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, You can use masked text box or create a custom control with richtextbox having underline and use it in client application. I heard there is a chance of creating textbox with underline using GDI+ api but not sure.

Thanks
Mahesh kotekar